# Bulk Database insertion not supported in iOS below 6.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

When inserting 400 row in single sqlite query in iOS 6.0.

```
e.g:  INSERT INTO MYTAB (NAME ,ADD) values("name1","add1"),("name2","add2"),("name3","add3"),.....
```

, works perfectly but when running same code in 5.0 it gives error:

> syntax error near ",".

Comment: This syntax wasn't supported before [SQLite 3.7.11](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html). [It seems that ios 5 uses older version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14288130/2286990).[Here's other relevant answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1609688/2286990).

Comment: I had asked a question that it gives error what is its solution.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a transaction and a prepared sqlite statement.

```
NSString* query;

if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    query = @"BEGIN TRANSACTION";
    ret = sqlite3_exec(database, [query UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL);

    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    NSString* str = @"INSERT INTO MYTAB (NAME, ADD) values (?,?)";
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [str UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, NULL);

    for (int i=0; i<50; i++)
    {
        const char *name = "name";
        const char *add = "add";

        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 1, name, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 2, add, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

        ret = sqlite3_step(compiledStatement);
        ret = sqlite3_reset(compiledStatement);
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

    query = @"COMMIT TRANSACTION";
    ret = sqlite3_exec(database, [query UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL);

    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vame .
I had done same using sqlite3_exe but it gives error.. also had set  "PRAGMA synchronous = OFF" after BEGIN TRANSACTION . but same error...

Comment: what kind of error? edit your question and post some code so we can see

Answer (score 0):

This syntax wasn't supported before [SQLite 3.7.11](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html):

> > Enhance the INSERT syntax to allow multiple rows to be inserted via the VALUES clause.

It seems that [iOS 5 uses 3.7.7, iOS 6 uses 3.7.13](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3720346/2286990) and that the reason why query failed in iOS 5.

You may still use separate INSERT statements or workaround mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5009740/2286990) or prepared statements, but if you simply need to pre-populate database efficiently then you may also follow [suggestions mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364017/faster-bulk-inserts-in-sqlite3).